# Wait() and NotifyAll() in my code doesn't work in a for loop

Tags: java, multithreading

I have this code:

```
private int           delay;
private int           x,y,R;
private int           dx=3 , dy=3;
private JLabel    box;
private Ball twin;
boolean isWaiting=false;
private  void  moveStep(){
    Dimension size= box.getSize();
    if (x<=0)
    {
        BounceTest.updateSide(0, BounceTest.getSideValue(0) + 1);
        dx = -dx;
        if(!isWaiting)
            twin.isWaiting=false;
            this.notifyAll();
    }


    if(x+2*R >=size.width){         // Bounce
        synchronized(BounceTest.sides[1])
        {
            BounceTest.updateSide(1, BounceTest.getSideValue(1) + 1);
            dx = -dx;
            this.notifyAll();
        }   
    }
    if (y<=0  ||  y+2*R >=size.height)
        dy = -dy;
    x += dx;
    y += dy;

}
public  synchronized void  run(){
    Color  bg = box.getBackground();
    Graphics  g = box.getGraphics();
    for (int i=0; i<5000; i++){

        draw(g,  Color.blue);                        // draw
        try {
            Thread.sleep(delay);                 // sleep
        } catch(InterruptedException e){}
        if(isWaiting)
        {
            System.out.println("ss1");
            try { 
                synchronized (twin) {
                    twin.wait(); 
                }

                }   catch(InterruptedException e) { }
            System.out.println("ss2");
        }
        draw(g, bg);                                     // delete
        moveStep();

    }
    g.dispose();
}
```

I have two threads that suppose to run by this same code, one is supposed to get to `twin.wait()` in the `run()` method and the other is supposed to call `NotifyAll()` in `moveStep()` method but the problem is when there is a for it doesn't call `NotifyAll()` and when I remove the  for it calls it, why is that and how I could fix it?

Comment: 1st, notifyAll has to be called in a synchronized block, 2nd, it's unclear how locking works because you haven't included what `twin` is.

Comment: i'm making two balls that have these part of the code the first ball gets the second ball as a twin and the second ball gets the first as a twin

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are doing wait onver twin (that makes the thread sleep over the object twin) and when you want to wake up that thread you are using notify over "this".

You should change your code using one of two options:

Option 1

change the:

```
this.notifyAll();
```

to

```
twin.notifyAll();
```

Option 2:

```
synchronized (twin) {
  twin.wait();
}
```

to

```
synchronized (this) {
  this.wait();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some inconsistencies in your code.

First, you should only call notify or notifyAll on the (an) object you are actually synchronizing on, not other ones (you'll get an IllegalMonitorStateException otherwise).

Synchronizing on BounceTest.sides[1] and then modifying the side inside the block might get you in trouble, too, depending on whether updateSide actually exchanges the object in sides[1] for another one, or simply modifies some fields in the object (this is okay).

Also, you should normally never have an empty catch block. Even for InterruptedExceptions, when you think they should not occur in your program: at least output them in a log file (or on the console for simple programs), so you know when something goes wrong.

You seem to have an `isWaiting` variable – but all we ever see is it getting set to false (if the one of the other thread is already false).

Then, your run method is synchronized (this is like a `synchronized(this)`-block), and you never ever wait on `this` inside this method (or moveStep). This means that the other thread has no chance to enter its `synchronized(twin)` block, and the two threads will block each other.

There might be other issues with your code, but start with these and then call back and show your results.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know when the "isWaiting" flag changed. NotifyAll() should be always called(if your code can go through that line), but it doesn't make any sense if you don't hold the monitor of the object on which you are calling the NotifyAll(); i suppose you want to wait until each moving complete, so i guess you should call "twin.notifyAll()" than "this.notifyAll()", because your main thread is waiting for the "twin"'s monitor not own one.

Answer (score 0):

Another problem is `isWaiting` is read outside of `synchronized`. The Java memory model makes no guarantees about changes that variable being visible to other threads. You can fix this in two ways. You can make the variable volatile, which makes sure the variable is always flushed to main memory rather than possibly a CPU l2/l3 cache. You can also read/manipulate the variable inside a synchronized statement. This guarantees that any changes to the variable will be visible to any other thread that synchronizes to the same lock.